# Add feature manually to a vector layer in ol3

Tags: vector, openlayers

I'm trying to add a layer manually to a vector layer with javascript.  I can't seem to determine why this is failing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/f4t6n6v1/4/

I've tried sane coordinates like 16,22, and big ones to match the view's xy values. I get a javascript error from ol3 : TypeError: b.Q is not a function.

HTML:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: vectorSource
      })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});

var thing = new ol.geom.Polygon( [ [16000000,22000000],[44000000,55000000],[88000000,90000000] ] );
vectorSource.addFeature( thing );
```

Comment: With ol3-debug.js, I get "AssertionError: Failure: unsupported stride: undefined"

Comment: You're trying to add a geometry to the source. Wrap it in an `ol.Feature` first.

Comment: Nice!  I was also missing the conversion from lat/long to y/x.  Updating the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/f4t6n6v1/7/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As [Gabor Farkas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/36475/gabor-farkas) said, I was adding the geometry and not a feature to the source.  I was also missing [] on the coordinates to the geometry, and wasn't converting properly.  Outside of here, I was using lat/long as x/y instead of y/x.  Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kieveli/f4t6n6v1/7/

HTML:

```
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});

var map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
      }),
      new ol.layer.Vector({
          source: vectorSource
      })
  ],
  target: 'map',
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [-11000000, 4600000],
    zoom: 4
  })
});

var thing = new ol.geom.Polygon( [[
    ol.proj.transform([-16,-22], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-44,-55], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    ol.proj.transform([-88,75], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')
]]);
var featurething = new ol.Feature({
    name: "Thing",
    geometry: thing
});
vectorSource.addFeature( featurething );
```