# nothing is displayed in my ol3 map

Tags: openlayers

I generated this geojson data in my server:

```
{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[30.0212,40.123],[30.0229,40.1235],[30.0246,40.1239],[30.0262,40.1241],[30.027,40.1241],[30.0283,40.1241]]}
```

in ol3 I did:

```
// data above the client via ajax
$.each(data , function (k,v) {
     console.log(k,v);

      var g1=JSON.parse(v);

      var vectorFeature = new ol.Feature({                    
                geometry: g1 ,                                       
      });

      featuresArr.push(vectorFeature); 

})

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector();

vectorSource.addFeatures(featuresArr);

var yol2=new ol.layer.Vector({               
            projection: 'EPSG:3857',
            source: [vectorSource]
        });

if( yol2 instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
                  // alert("yol2");
                  olTrMap.addLayer( yol2);

               }
```

Then nothing is displayed.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

See this question [Add feature manually to a vector layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153092/add-feature-manually-to-a-vector-layer-in-ol3).

`coordinates` should be transform. check your coordinate system.